# How do I assign a variable with `val` within a code block so it's accessible afterwards?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to do something like the following:

```kotlin
suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product> {
  runBlocking {
    launch {
      val inAppProducts = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        queryProductDetails(...)
      }
    }
    launch {
      val subsProducts = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        queryProductDetails(...)
      }
    }
  }
  return inAppProducts + subsProducts
}
```

*(Note: Ignoring null checks and function arguments for brevity)*

Two questions:

1. How do I initialize the `val` and use it outside of the code block? Is `var` the only option?
2. Is this good coding style?

Comment: You could just delete `runBlocking` which serves no purpose.

Comment: @dominicoder My bad - updated my question to include the `launch` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `runBlocking` in a suspend function. A suspend function must not block by convention. You can instead use `coroutineScope` or `withContext` to be able to launch parallel coroutines inside your suspend function.

`launch` is for coroutines that don’t produce anything. Use `async` instead if you want to produce something. This starts running the coroutine in parallel right away. Then call `await()` on the coroutine’s Deferred to get the result in a suspend function.

```
suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product> = coroutineScope {
  val inAppProducts = async {
    queryProductDetails(...)
  }
  val subsProducts = async {
    queryProductDetails(...)
  }
  return@withContext inAppProducts.await() + subsProducts.await()
}
```

If `queryProductDetails()` is a suspend function, then switching to the IO dispatcher is kind of pointless (unless we are joining enormous lists) and we can replace `withContext` with `coroutineScope`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! So, queryProductDetails is a suspend function [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#querying_with_kotlin_extensions). I'm unable to add `async` unless I include it inside of `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` i.e. `val inAppProducts = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { async { queryProductDetails(...)}}`. Does that seem correct?

Comment: Note the outermost `withContext` in my code—no need to use it twice. But since queryProductDetails is a suspend function, you could use `coroutineScope` instead to make it slightly simpler. `withContext` and `coroutineScope` are basically the same except that `withContext` also lets you modify the CoroutineContext.

Comment: Ah I missed the outermost `withContext`, thank you! It works now. But you're right in the other comment, there's a lot about `withContext` and `coroutineScope` that I don't fully understand. Do you have any recommended resources that will be helpful to understand these better?

Comment: I don't know a single resource that explains it all in one place clearly. :( The [documentation for the `coroutineScope` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) is pretty clear and succinct. You can think of `withContext` as the same thing plus the ability to modify the CoroutineContext. It's most commonly used to enforce a specific Dispatcher. You only need to enforce a dispatcher when calling blocking code or when calling a function that only works on a specific thread, like working with Views that require Main.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that the reason for runBlocking and launching two coroutines is that you want the two to run in parallel and then wait for both results. If so, that's what [async](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) is for.

Sample pseudocode that may or may not be technically correct but you illustrate the idea:

```
suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product> {
    // Start first job and get a handle to it
    val inAppProductsJob = async {
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        queryProductDetails(...)
      }
    }

    // Start second job and get a handle to it
    val subsProductsJob = async {
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        queryProductDetails(...)
      }
    }

  // Waits for both jobs to complete, gets their results, and combines them
  return inAppProducts.await() + subsProducts.await()
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap this function in either `withContext` or `coroutineScope` though or you won’t have access to a receiver CoroutineScope to call `async` with.

Comment: Yeah, I just tweaked the OP's own code to illustrate the idea, I didn't test it for correctness.

Comment: I assume they were using `runBlocking` to be able to launch other coroutines, so lack of knowledge about `withContext` and `coroutineScope`, which give you a coroutine scope without blocking is half their problem.

Comment: Instead of `async { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... } }`, why not `async(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }`?